# Can a reinterpret_cast itself cause an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, memory, casting

Suppose I have a class called A, and a void pointer vp. Can the following ever cause an exception?

```
A *ap = reinterpret_cast<A*>(vp);
```

Thank you,
Fijoy

Comment: No. It is a purely compile-time construct. It is very dangerous, because it lets you get away with very wrong conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming (which you can in your case since it's of type `void*`) the *expression* `vp` doesn't throw an exception (it could do if it was an object of a type that had a hand-crafted conversion operator that threw an exception), then

`A *ap = reinterpret_cast<A*>(vp);`

will not itself throw an exception.

*dereferencing* `ap` *could* cause an exception to be thrown however.

Comment: How could dereferencing an invalid pointer cause an exception? I could understand a segfault.

Comment: The behaviour is undefined. So it *could* throw an exception. It could even eat your cat.

Comment: I have the same question. Would dereferencing or accessing a member of ap generate exception, or will it be a segfault?

Comment: You don't know. The behaviour is undefined. Nothing more can be said. In other words, you can't sort of *try* a dereference and rely on any sort of mechanism to catch naughty ones.

Comment: @FijoyVadakkumpadan It could be a segfault, or it could be nothing. Unfortunately, undefined behavior is like that.

Comment: OK, the message I'm getting is this: dereferencing or accessing a member of (using the -> operator) a bad pointer either causes a segfault or unexpected results. It typically does not cause an exception, so wrapping a dereferencing or member access operation inside a try{} block isn't typically useful. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Fijoy it depends on the implementation, in MSVC++ `try
 {
  std::cout << *static_cast<int*>(nullptr);
 }
 catch (...)
 {
  std::cout << "exception" << std::endl;
 }` will print 'exception' (when compiled with '/EHa')

Answer (score 6):

No, neither a `reinterpret_cast<T>` nor its C-style cast equivalent perform any checking, so they cannot by themselves cause an exception. Obviously, since both constructs are about as unsafe as it gets, dereferencing the result pointer `ap` could cause undefined behavior.